# How to divide a string to a list of substrings in list, but keeping the number strings intact - Python?

Tags: python, list

all. I'm trying to split a specific string into a somethings like this:

```
a = '1+2j'
b = '23j'
c = '12'
...
a_list = ['1', '+2', 'j']
b_list = ['23', 'j']
c_list = ['12']
```

I want to do it so that one set of code will satisfy with all the strings a, b, and c into a_list, b_list and c_list. The rules should be that the numbers will always stay with the same numbers and the positive and negative signs will always be connected to the number - for example `12+2j` will become '12' '+2', 'j', `-2-23j` would become '-2' '-23' 'j'. How can I do this?? I tried the `re.compile` method but it didn't really work for me...

Any ways??

Comment: Do you expect us to know under what rule to divide? [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could split by digit groups:

```
import re

a = '1+2j'
b = '23j'
c = '12'


def split(s, pat=re.compile(r'(\d+)')):
    return [e for e in pat.split(s) if e]


print(split(a))
print(split(b))
print(split(c))
```

**Output**

```
['1', '+', '2', 'j']
['23', 'j']
['12']
```

Using a [capture group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) inside the pattern allows to keep the delimiter.